# Словари не хотят водных часов, только водяные, - как быть?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов, словари

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня:

> В садах на вилле Боргезе есть **водные часы**, чуть ли не барочные.
>   Надо повнимательнее почитать про их устройство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общепринятое название — **водяные часы**, что соответствует одному из значений суффикса ЯН в словаре Ефремовой: работающий на том, что названо мотивирующим словом (ветряной, водяной, торфяной).

Иногда встречается название **водные часы,** например: Маленький гений / Научный набор. Водные часы. https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/3108786/detail.aspx

Но в этом случае вода не является непосредственно рабочей жидкостью: на воде работают батарейки, а часы получаются электрические. Здесь используется суффикс относительного прилагательного Н с общим значением.

Поэтому **водные часы** — это скорее **авторское название** (возможно, допускается как упрощенный вариант).